# Son necesarias las etiquetas header, section, footer etc

Tags: html, css, html5

Sé crear un sitio web, pero nunca lo he hecho usando las etiquetas header etc... Solo con divs,  no sé si está mal hecho pero el problema es que ya tengo lista una web que tenía que entregar, es necesario usar estas etiquetas?

Comment: No, no es necesario usar esas etiquetas. Son totalmente opcional.

Comment: No, aunque ayudan a organizar el código y estructurar la web de forma más semántica, también son interpretadas por los robots de los buscadores y si se usan bien pueden mejorar el SEO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, no es necesario, pero es aconsejable:

`<div>` es la abreviación de *división*, luego es un elemento que sirve para crear divisiones o "zonas" en un documento. Pero más allá de su significado técnico no aporta nada desde el punto de vista semántico.

Imagina a alguien que no pueda usar un navegador normal por tener problemas de visión y use un lector de pantallas: Saber qué parte de la página es la principal, cuál es el menú de navegación y qué partes son secundarias es complicado si no hay más indicaciones. Para ayudar con la semántica aparecieron nuevas etiquetas en el estándar HTML (versión 5) que ayudan a definir no sólo "zonas" visuales, sino la función de esas zonas. De este modo ahora se prima más *qué quieres representar* que el *cómo* en el HTML. Un ejemplo:

- Tienes un párrafo -> lo indicas con `<p>`.
- En ese párrafo quiere enfatizar una palabra o frase: antes usarías `<b>` o `<i>`, para elegir entre poner `bold` (negrita) o *itálica*. Estas etiquetas están hoy día desaconsejadas porque indican el cómo visualizar, que es tarea de los estilos (CSS). Lo correcto sería usar `<em>` (emphasize) o `<strong>` (fuerte relevancia) o `<mark>` (importante en el contexto).
- Mediante CSS puedes elegir cómo modifica cada etiqueta el texto: todo en mayúsculas, negrita, itálica, letras más grandes, subrayado, tachado... etc.

Del mismo modo, los buscadores indexan la información de las páginas conocidas según su temática, contenido, accesibilidad... con lo que usar las etiquetas correctas les ayuda (y por tanto te ayuda) a clasificar mejor tu página.